# Async Task - Force close

Tags: android, android-asynctask, forceclose

This call is done in the `onCreate`:

```
new retreive().execute();
```

The `asyncTask` class looks like this:

```
class retreive extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(busDisp.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        this.dialog.setMessage("Retreiving Bus Routes...");
        this.dialog.show();
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        busRouteJsonParsing();
        this.dialog.dismiss();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void voids){
            setContentView(R.layout.buses);
            stop1.setText(Integer.valueOf(stopsCtr[0]).toString()+" stops");
            stop2.setText(Integer.valueOf(stopsCtr[1]).toString()+" stops");
            stop3.setText(Integer.valueOf(stopsCtr[2]).toString()+" stops");
            stop4.setText(Integer.valueOf(stopsCtr[3]).toString()+" stops");
            dur1.setText(dur[0]);
            dur2.setText(dur[1]);
            dur3.setText(dur[2]);
            dur4.setText(dur[3]);
            this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

There are 8 `onClicks` after this on `PostExecute`

This is the log:

```
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982): Activity com.example.Try1.busDisp has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418b7ad8 that was originally added here
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.Try1.busDisp has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418b7ad8 that was originally added here
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at com.example.Try1.busDisp$retreive.onPreExecute(busDisp.java:249)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at com.example.Try1.busDisp.onCreate(busDisp.java:91)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
12-20 19:55:57.701: E/WindowManager(982):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting a force close on line 249.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included line numbers in your snip but the crash is happening in `onPreExecute()` It looks like a problem with the window token, perhaps you should create the dialog from scratch in `onPreExecute()` or create it in `onCreate()` and make it a class member, that way your `AsyncTask` can still access it easily.

You should also call `show()` last once you've set everything else up on the dialog, that way you avoid changing it's state while it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use  `this.dialog.dismiss();` in your doinbackground process. 
UI updates are wont work in Async Task Doinbackground processes. 
All the UI updates will work only in Post Execute and PreExecute ..

Hope this will help you.